# Make the tag wayback-machine a synonym of archive.org

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, there are two tags on this site [wayback-machine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wayback-machine) and [archive.org](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org).

- [archive.org](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org) is the older of the two. It has 29 questions at the moment, and it also has a [tag-excerpt](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/70213/revisions) and a [tag-wiki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/70212/revisions). The tag excerpt says: "The Internet Archive and the Wayback Machine."
- The tag [wayback-machine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wayback-machine) only has two questions, one of them has both of these tags. (I have posted those two questions [in this site's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/7/2020/6/29) - so they can be found there even if the tag gets removed.)
- [wayback-machine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wayback-machine) was also created (and then removed) back in 2014: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/69847/revisions (Some relevant SEDE queries: [adding this tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=wayback-machine), [removing this tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1038474/questions-which-no-longer-have-the-given-tag-including-the-editor?tagName=wayback-machine), [deleted posts with this tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/883845/deleted-questions-with-a-given-tag?Tagname=wayback-machine).)

**Proposal:** Create a tag-synonym [wayback-machine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wayback-machine) → [archive.org](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org).

Of course, the tag with only two questions could easily be manually retagged. But I consider the synonym suitable. Both names for this site are commonly used, so people trying to add suitable tags to their question are likely to try either of them. Moreover, with the tag synonym in place, it is no longer possible for the tag to be created and removed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Martin](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20838/martin), thank you for flagging that your question was never answered or tagged `status-completed`.

For the record, [wayback-machine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wayback-machine) became a synonym for [archive.org](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive.org) Feb. 23, 2023.

Thank you for your original suggestion and following up!